# When should we use setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) or setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)?

Tags: android, admob, gdprconsentform

I am implementing UMP sdk and the consent request paremeters can be set with setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) or setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false). I have been like many days confused because of this as the only official documentation is: "Gets the TFUA value sets by ConsentRequestParameters.Builder.setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(boolean)."

I have seen that I am not the only one with this exact doubt although I have not seen any other question about this: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/d81PwAyiveo

Please, could someone explain clearly when should I use setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true) or setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(false)?

```
    ConsentRequestParameters params = new ConsentRequestParameters
            .Builder()
            .setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(true or false!?)
            .build();
```

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting

Comment: that documentation is for RequestConfiguration, not for ConsentRequestParameters. Notice that RequestConfiguration.setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(int) recieves an int while ConsentRequestParameters.setTagForUnderAgeOfConsent(boolean) recieves a boolean

Comment: Like I said on your other question, you set it to *true* if the user is under the age of consent, and *false* if they're not. It's an EEA thing relating to GDPR compliance - if you're serving ads to users there, then you're supposed to set this tag so the ads you serve comply with regulations. You can read about what it specifically does here: https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9009425?hl=en Honestly if you have any more specific questions about your situation you might be better asking on the Admob and UMP support forums, it's hard for anyone here to tell you exactly what you should do